# A word that describes something you shouldn't have said

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember it being a Latin or French term. It must be a synonym for *bêtise*–“a foolish or ill-timed remark or action.” But I can't find it anywhere now.

It describes a moment where you said something inappropriate, showing a lack of awareness in reading the room.

Comment: Single word requests should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: 'Make a **faux pas**' perhaps?

Comment: “Did you enjoy the show, Mrs Lincoln?” could be described as a *bêtise* or as an *indiscretion*, or as @Boldben’s *Faux pas*, which deserves the credit of being an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: Faux pas was exactly what I was going for. Thanks so much dude.

Comment: @Anton Thanks for the suggestion. I've upgraded it to a properly referenced answer (and learned how long it's been a part of English in the process). If user401093 will accept the answer the question might not come up for review!

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be looking for [faux pas](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/faux%20pas) which was borrowed from French (it's French for "false step") as far back as the late 17th century.

Merriam Webster defines it as

> a significant or embarrassing error or mistake

> especially : a socially awkward or improper act or remark